# JButton only appears after mouse rolls over it

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paint, repaint

I have this GUI class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Exp2 extends JFrame {
    public Exp2 () {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(360, 360);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        add(panel2);
        add(panel1);
        panel1.paint(null);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Run");
        panel2.add(button1, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

along with this main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
class Exp1 extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exp2 box = new Exp2();
    }
}
```

But the JButton `button1` only appears after I roll my mouse over where it should be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By the way, you should override `paintComponent`, not `paint`.

Comment: 1) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one. 2) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.

Comment: @WChargin  You should try that (before recommending it).

Comment: What was your thinking when you added `panel1.paint(null);`?  Programming does not work by magic, and trying 'every last thing' will usually not solve the problem.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I've just started GUIs in Java and I found a tutorial which uses `paint(null)`

Comment: @AndrewThompson I meant in general (in conjunction with your first comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never call

```
super.paint(g);
```

which paints the containers child components.

Don't do custom painting in a top level container such as `JFrame`. Rather move the paint functionality to a subclass of `JComponent`. There override `paintComponent` rather than `paint` and invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`. This takes advantage of the improved performance of Swing double buffering mechanism.

See: [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 2):

Call a `repaint` on the `JFrame` after you've added everything. Additionally, you need to call `super.paint(g)` from your `paint` method.

Comment: +1, for the repaint() which directly addresses the question. @OP a better approach is to add all the components to the frame first. Then invoke pack() and setVisible(true). Let Swing determine the preferred size of the frame, instead of you choosing some random number. You should NOT be overriding the paint() method of a JFrame.